# Is there any way to represent a bipartite graph other than adjacency matrix or a list?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suggest a scheme to represent a bipartite graph (G) with two sets A and B such that
(A Union B) = G and (A intersection B) = ø
which should be different from the adjacency matrix or list.

I was given a question in an assignment and these are the exact words used in the question.

Comment: What is the actual objective? What does the graph represent? Is the graph immutable or mutable? What operations will be performed on it? How large will the graph be? Is this for in-memory use or will it be persisted to-disk? Would you be mutating it on-disk?

Comment: "with two sets A and B which should be different from the adjacency matrix or list" - please explain what you mean by this. A set is 1-dimensional and a matrix is 2-dimensional - a comparison between a set and a matrix is meaningless.

Comment: Also, what programming language are you using? Depending on the language, you can take advantage of built-in language features, for example, if you're using C or C++ you can use a hash-set of raw object pointers.

Comment: I am using c++  here.

Comment: SO is not for doing your homework. You should try to solve it yourself and ask the doubts you have after doing some research on your own, not just come here and ask for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since your post mentions explicitly bipartite graphs and adjacency matrix, here is a possibility. Nevertheless, as @Dal said in comments, this is far from being the only solution; there is no silver bullet when it comes to representing graphs.

First, you need to index the elements of A and B (meaning, store each in an array). Then you can represent the bipartite graph as a `A x B` matrix, since you have the guarantee that all edges are between a vertex of `A` and a vertex of `B`. The memory footprint will be smaller than a full adjacency matrix.